# How do i insert values into a column within a specific row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

I'm trying to insert table values into my postgreSQL database into a certain row but struggling, any ideas?

The code I've been using is the following but it keeps returning errors.For clarity,
`applicationname` and `applicationemail` are the values and `role_id` is personal to the row.

I know the following code is wrong but it's the closest line i can think of achieving it.

Where am i going wrong?

```
    await pool2.query(
      "INSERT INTO contracts (applicationname, applicationemail) VALUES ($1, $2) WHERE role_id = $3",
      [name, email, role_id]
    );
```

*disclaimer, I'm recently new to coding any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I get "error at where" when i console log it?

Comment: If you want to change an existing row, you need to use `UPDATE`, not INSERT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the obvious error is syntaxis error: [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html) command does not have WHERE clause. This is the reason for the raisng error.

The second error is logical:  [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html) command adds a NEW row in the table.
To modify the EXSITNG row you need [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-update.html) command it has WHERE clause (as sad @a_horse_with_no_name)